# WritePrivateProfileString works in main but not in function

Tags: c++, parsing, ini

I am trying to use WritePrivateProfileString and GetPrivateProfileInt for a `.ini` parser.

When I put the code below into `main()`, or into a class constructor, it works for writing and reading.

But, when I make functions for writing and reading, and call the functions in `main()`, nothing happens, although the functions are run as they will `cout` something if I ask them to.

Here is the test program I wrote to demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define CStringify(x) std::to_string(x).c_str()

int testvar = 12;
int returntestvar = 0;
std::fstream config;

std::string configstring = ".//config.ini";

int main()
{   
    WriteINI();
    ReadINI();
    std::cout << returntestvar << std::endl;
    getchar();
}

void WriteINI()
{
    config.open("config.ini", std::ios::app);
    WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "Test1", CStringify(testvar), configstring.c_str());
}

 void ReadINI()
{
    config.open("config.ini", std::ios::app);
    returntestvar = GetPrivateProfileInt("Test", "Test1", 0, configstring.c_str());
}
```

The above code creates and then edits an `.ini` file, as it is expected to.

However, if I move the code into a class, it will no longer work.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "INIClassTest.h"

extern INIParser* Parse;

int main()
{   
    Parse->WriteINI();
    Parse->ReadINI();
    std::cout << Parse->returntestvar << std::endl;
    getchar();
}
```

INIClassTest.h

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

#define CStringify(x) std::to_string(x).c_str()

class INIParser
{
public:
    INIParser();
    void WriteINI();
    void ReadINI();

    int testvar;
    int returntestvar;
    std::fstream config;
    std::string configstring;

};

extern INIParser* Parse;
```

INIClassTest.cpp

```
#include "INIClassTest.h"
#include <iostream>

INIParser* Parse = new INIParser();

INIParser::INIParser()
{
    returntestvar = 0;
    testvar = 18;
    std::string configstring = ".//config.ini";
}

void INIParser::WriteINI()
{
    config.open("config.ini", std::ios::app);
    WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "Test1", CStringify(testvar), configstring.c_str());
}

void INIParser::ReadINI()
{
    config.open("config.ini", std::ios::app);
    returntestvar = GetPrivateProfileInt("Test", "Test1", 0, configstring.c_str());
}
```

The above code creates an `.ini` file, but it doesn't edit it or return anything.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem so far?

Comment: "*The above code creates and then edits an .ini file, as it is expected to*" - no, it doesn't, because `main()` never calls `WriteINI()` or `ReadINI()`. Also, you should NOT be using an `fstream` at all to create/open the INI file manually. `WritePrivateProfileString()` and `GetPrivateProfileInt()` handle that for you. And if you read their documentation, DO NOT use a relative path for the INI file, or else the file will be relative to the Windows installation folder, not your app folder.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information about fstream and the relative path, I'll edit the code a bit. What do you mean main never calls WriteINI() or ReadINI()?

Comment: The first piece of code you posted does not call your functions. It's confusing which example you're referring to, and IMO the macro is a terrible idea.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the first code snipped. I wasn't really paying attention to that one when he said the functions weren't being called. Kept looking at the other code.

Comment: I made the changes that @RemyLebeau suggested but nothing changed and no .ini file is created.

Comment: @supex0fan I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT be using an `fstream` at all to create/open the INI file manually. `WritePrivateProfileString()` and `GetPrivateProfileInt()` handle that for you.

Also, if you read their documentation, you would see that you SHOULD NOT use a relative path for the INI file, or else the file will be relative to the Windows installation folder, not your app folder.  So, you probably ARE reading/writing the INI file, just not where you are expecting from/to.  If you want your INI file to be relative to your app's folder, you need to retrieve the path of your app's folder <sup>1</sup> and append the INI filename to it.

<sup>1</sup>: that is really not a good idea in general, though.  Depending on where you install your app, the user might not have write access to that folder.  You should instead use `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to get the user's local `%AppData%` folder, then create your own subfolder inside of it, and then create your INI file inside of that subfolder.

Try this instead:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define CStringify(x) std::to_string(x).c_str()

std::string GetAppFolder();
std::string GetINIPath();
void WriteINI();
void ReadINI();

int testvar = 12;
int returntestvar = 0;
std::string configstring = GetINIPath();

int main()
{   
    WriteINI();
    ReadINI();
    std::cout << returntestvar << std::endl;    
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

std::string GetAppFolder()
{
    char szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD len = GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
    std::string result(szFileName, len);
    std::string::size_type pos = result.find_last_of("\\/");
    result.resize(pos+1);
    return result;
}

std::string GetINIPath()
{
    return GetAppFolder() + "config.ini";
}

void WriteINI()
{
    WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "Test1", CStringify(testvar), configstring.c_str());
}

void ReadINI()
{
    returntestvar = GetPrivateProfileInt("Test", "Test1", 0, configstring.c_str());
}
```

The main reason your `INIParser` class fails is because your constructor is storing the INI file path in a local variable named `configstring`, instead of in the class's member also named `configstring`.  Thus, the class member is blank when `WriteINI()` and `ReadINI()` are called.

Try this instead:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "INIClassTest.h"

int main()
{   
    Parse.WriteINI();
    Parse.ReadINI();
    std::cout << Parse.returntestvar << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

INIClassTest.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class INIParser
{
public:
    INIParser();
    void WriteINI();
    void ReadINI();

    int testvar;
    int returntestvar;
    std::string configstring;
};

extern INIParser Parse;
```

INIClassTest.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "INIClassTest.h"
#include <string>

#define CStringify(x) std::to_string(x).c_str()

INIParser Parse;

static std::string GetAppFolder()
{
    char szFileName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD len = GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
    std::string result(szFileName, len);
    std::string::size_type pos = result.find_last_of("\\/");
    result.resize(pos+1);
    return result;
}

static std::string GetINIPath()
{
    return GetAppFolder() + "config.ini";
}

INIParser::INIParser()
{
    returntestvar = 0;
    testvar = 18;
    configstring = GetINIPath();
}

void INIParser::WriteINI()
{
    WritePrivateProfileString("Test", "Test1", CStringify(testvar), configstring.c_str());
}

void INIParser::ReadINI()
{
    returntestvar = GetPrivateProfileInt("Test", "Test1", 0, configstring.c_str());
}
```